# Newbie generic parameter qu estion... <T>

Tags: java

Okay so can i achive this somehow:

```
String myString = "someString";
Class myClass = myString.getClass();

HashMap<mClass, Integer> = new HashMap<myClass, Integer>();
```

So i would like to create a new hashmap, with class type of the key of my variables like Integer or String...

Comment: This isn't really possible. Generics are a compile-time construct, they express higher-order type constraints.

Comment: Yes i know it is not compiling i just wanted to tell what i would like to do

Comment: What you'd like to do doesn't make sense in Java's type system.

Comment: Doesnt make sense. It just does not make any sense. Thanks!

Comment: What do you want map against what? Give a real example of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not possible.** I'll walk you through the possibilities.

You could create a helper method, using generics. This will work because of all generics are compiled into simple `Object`s.

```
public static <T> Map<T, Integer> createMap(Class<T> cl)
{
    return new HashMap<T, Integer>();
}
```

Now, you could use it like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = createMap(String.class);
```

However, this will require you to know what T is at compile time. So this won't work:

```
String str = "Test";
Class cl = str.getClass();
Map<String, Integer> map = createMap(cl); // Doesn't compile.
```

So, to conclude, this helper method isn't worth anything, because you could simply write:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Comment: The `? extends T` construct seems pretty useless here.

Answer (score 0):

Due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) this would not work.
A possible (but more verbose way) is to create a factory method that returns a Map based on the passed argument, eg:

```
MapFactory.create(String.class);
```

EDIT: In answer to @millimoose comment about this being not different from direct instantiation (which is true):

You could try to implement your own Map or decorate or extend the HashMap implementation so that it retains type information.

Comment: Of course this brings no benefits over `new HashMap<String>()`. The type still has to be known at compile-time where the map is being created.